# Why compiler use a 32bit register to pass a pointer to a function on a amd64 linux in this situation

Tags: c, ssl, assembly, x86-64, chromium

[image]I'm debuging  a chromium  with a modified boringssl.It always got a SegmentFault.
I found the problem is

```
EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));
```

Disassembled code:

```
callq EC_KEY_get0_group
mov %eax,%edi
callq EC_GROUP_get_curve_name
```

The return type of `EC_KEY_get0_group` is a `EC_GROUP*` pointer,but it was passed to `EC_GROUP_get_curve_name` by a 32bit register.

The pointer was truncated and it caused the SegmentFault. Why compiler generates code like this?
Is there any compiler option to avoid this?

Comment: The likely problem is that  `EC_KEY_get0_group` hasn't been property declared at that point in the program, so the compiler assumes `int` as the function return type.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings and check if there are any warnings during compilation.  There should be some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can offer guidance to track down the issue, but not a specific answer to your question since I don't have the modified version of BoringSSL being used.

---

If you don't have prototypes for the *C* function then all the parameters and return values will default to an `int` type. The function will be treated as if there are an unspecified number of parameters.

The first thing that stood out to me was the `mov $0, %al` before each function call. This suggested to me that these functions are either variadic or prototypeless. The [AMD64 System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) used by 64-bit Linux describes the *AL* register this way:

> For calls that may call functions that use varargs or stdargs (prototype-less
> calls or calls to functions containing ellipsis (. . . ) in the declaration) %al is used
> as hidden argument to specify the number of vector registers used.

We can rule out them being variadic since the prototypes for them are supposed to be something like:

```
int EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(const EC_GROUP *group);
const EC_GROUP *EC_KEY_get0_group(const EC_KEY *key);
```

Since these functions aren't variadic (don't use `...`) then it is likely something in your code that isn't making the prototypes for these functions available.

---

We can see this same behaviour with these simple C function call:

**testfunc.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ec_group_st EC_GROUP;
typedef struct ec_key_st EC_KEY;

int EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(const EC_GROUP *group);
const EC_GROUP *EC_KEY_get0_group(const EC_KEY *key);

int testfun()
{
    EC_KEY *ec = NULL;
    return EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));
}
```

If I use GCC to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -c -O3 testfunc.c -o testfunc.o` and use `objdump -D testfunc.o` to look at the generated code it looks like:

```
0000000000000000 <testfun>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
   6:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  b <testfun+0xb>
   b:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
   f:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  12:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   17 <testfun+0x17>
```

The code above seems correct as the 64-bit return value (pointer in *RAX*) from the first function call is passed to the second function call as expected. The code doesn't set *AL* to zero either.

If however I take the same code and comment out the prototypes for the functions like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ec_group_st EC_GROUP;
typedef struct ec_key_st EC_KEY;

/*int EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(const EC_GROUP *group);
const EC_GROUP *EC_KEY_get0_group(const EC_KEY *key);*/

int testfun()
{
    EC_KEY *ec = NULL;
    return EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));
}
```

I get this generated code:

```
0000000000000000 <testfun>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
   6:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   8:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  d <testfun+0xd>
   d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  11:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  13:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  15:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1a <testfun+0x1a>
```

Now we have *RAX*(*AL* being the lower 8 bits of *RAX*) being set to zero and the return value from the first function call is being treated as a 32-bit `int` which is similar to the behaviour you are seeing. I recommend at least building your *C* files with `-Wall -Wextra` to see a wider variety of warnings. In the case of the code without prototypes my compiler threw these warnings:

```
testfunc.c: In function ‘testfun’:
testfunc.c:12:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘EC_GROUP_get_curve_name’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaratio
]
     return EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testfunc.c:12:36: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘EC_KEY_get0_group’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec));
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I would look for similar kinds of warning about implicit declarations in your build output and verify in your code that the function prototypes have been properly included.

Comment: Note that implicit-declaration warnings are on by default for GCC versions new enough to default to `-std=gnu99`, i.e. GCC5 https://godbolt.org/z/xxb9YY. GCC4.9 and earlier default to C89/GNU89, and only warn about this with `-Wall`, and/or with `-std=gnu99`.  Even the earliest clang (3.0) on Godbolt warns about implicit declarations by default, unless you use `-std=gnu89`.  So using a more up to date compiler would also have made this very important warning hard to miss.